# Usage of "so that"

Tags: phrases

I am working on a paper, and the following phrasing was suggested:

> In the protein-protein interaction
>   (PPI) network, nodes represent
>   proteins and edges represent
>   connections between them, based on
>   experimental evidence. PPI networks
>   are rich and complex, **so that**
>   a mathematical model is sought to
>   capture their properties and shed
>   light on PPI evolution.

Is that a <s>legal</s> legitimate use of *so that*? How would you phrase it differently otherwise?

Comment: "Legal" is not a word I would use to describe English usage. The Grammar Police, for all their bluster, have no authority to arrest you and put you into Grammar Prison.

Comment: @Robusto: They may in Nazi Grammarland...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is a valid use of “so that”.

> **so that:** with the result that (*it was overgrown with brambles, so that I had difficulty making any*)

(*New Oxford American Dictionary*). Not to be confused with another use of *so that*, namely:

> **so that:** with the aim that; in order that (*they whisper to each other so that no one else can hear*)

Comment: I know that is the example from the dictionary but I would leave _that_ out because it's effectively redundant.

Comment: I disagree. Your first definition doesn't fit OP's context any better than the second. However I read it, OP's construction implies that the "**seeking** of a mathematical model" is somehow *intended* or *caused* by the fact that PPI networks are rich and complex. I think it's just poor writing.

Comment: I disagree also. It should say "so", not "so that". The sentence sounds as though it is saying "PPI networks are rich and complex in order that a mathematical model is sought", which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think that wording was used to try and emphasize the complexity, but it does read a bit strangely.

The emphasis might have been better expressed something like the following:

> ... PPI networks are rich and complex, **so much so**, that a mathematical model is sought to
>   capture their properties and shed light on PPI evolution.

Answer (score 0):

I think it reads odd too, but not because of **so that**, but because of **is sought**.

I would have written:  ...so that a mathematical model **may be** sought to capture their properties and shed light on PPI evolution.

Answer (score 0):

I think it means that a person did something to aim at a certain point. For example:

> Sam did his homework so that he could play with his friend.

If *so that* is replaced with "to aim at" or "in order to", it would fit well since the three words mean the same thing. For example:

> Sam did his work to aim at playing with his friends.
>   Sam did his work in order to play with with his friends.

Comment: but so that is different from so----that----------

Answer (score 0):

"So that" doesn't sound right to me, it makes it sound like you're saying PPI networks are complex *because* a mathematical model is sought. Even if it were correct, it's needlessly verbose. A better phrasing might be:

> PPI networks are rich and complex, **and** a mathematical model is sought to capture their properties and shed light on PPI evolution.